# How to solve exponential equation without using logarithm , $10=(\frac{6}{5})^x$

Tags: exponential-function

Without using logarithms, how can I solve

$$10=\left(\frac{6}{5}\right)^x$$

Comment: Why should we not use the obvious approach to solve this ? An alternative could be Newton's method as a numerical approach.

Comment: $(6/5)^4=1296/625\gt1250/625=2$,so $(6/5)^{16}\gt2^4\gt10$, so $x\lt16$

Comment: Since the answer involves logarithm, I don't see how an analytical approach could avoid it. Your only option is numerical solution.

Comment: Trial and error for 58 minutes $x\approx 12.6293$

Answer (score 0):

You could use the series expansion of the natural logarithm as follows:

$$
\frac{\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n}\left(1-\frac{1}{10}\right)^{n}}{\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n}\left(1-\frac{5}{6}\right)^{n}}
$$

Therefore, you don't use the logarithm directlry. But I am not sure, if this infinite sum is better for you. At least it will approach the correct result, the more terms you use.